# Want to use DECODE in my query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have written a procedure and in that there are multiple Sql statements I have used but in one statement I got stuck so my problem is in the below query. There is a refnum in my query named as ULE.ULE_ORIGINAL_PFS and the value of this refnum could be either a number or MASTER_DATA_NO_AVAILABLE or INVALID_ENTRY     so my requirement is whenever the value of the refnum is MASTER_DATA_NO_AVAILABLE  or INVALID_ENTRY then I have to consider it as a '0' so kindly help me out on this as I am confused to use either DECODE or NVL.

```
SELECT SUM(ORF.ORDER_RELEASE_REFNUM_VALUE)
INTO V_OR_ORIGINAL_PFS
FROM ORDER_RELEASE_REFNUM ORF ,
VIEW_SHIPMENT_ORDER_RELEASE VSOR,
SHIPMENT SH ,
ORDER_RELEASE ORR
WHERE ORF.ORDER_RELEASE_GID           = VSOR.ORDER_RELEASE_GID
AND VSOR.SHIPMENT_GID                 = SH.SHIPMENT_GID
AND ORR.ORDER_RELEASE_GID             = ORF.ORDER_RELEASE_GID
AND ORF.ORDER_RELEASE_REFNUM_QUAL_GID = 'ULE.ULE_ORIGINAL_PFS'
AND SH.SHIPMENT_GID        = P_SHIPMENT_GID
AND ORR.ORDER_RELEASE_GID IN
(SELECT ORR.ORDER_RELEASE_GID
FROM VIEW_SHIPMENT_ORDER_RELEASE VSOR,
SHIPMENT SH ,
ORDER_RELEASE ORR
WHERE VSOR.ORDER_RELEASE_GID = ORR.ORDER_RELEASE_GID
AND VSOR.SHIPMENT_GID        = SH.SHIPMENT_GID
AND SH.SHIPMENT_GID            = P_SHIPMENT_GID
AND ORR.ORDER_RELEASE_GID NOT IN
(SELECT ORF.ORDER_RELEASE_GID
FROM VIEW_SHIPMENT_ORDER_RELEASE VSOR,
SHIPMENT SH ,
ORDER_RELEASE_REFNUM ORF
WHERE VSOR.ORDER_RELEASE_GID          = ORF.ORDER_RELEASE_GID
AND VSOR.SHIPMENT_GID                 = SH.SHIPMENT_GID
AND ORF.ORDER_RELEASE_REFNUM_QUAL_GID = 'ULE.ULE_UNPLANNED_ICT'
AND SH.SHIPMENT_GID                   = P_SHIPMENT_GID
)
);
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like this `decode(ULE_ORIGINAL_PFS,'MASTER_DATA_NO_AVAILABLE',0,'INVALID_ENTRY',0,ULE_ORIGINAL_PFS)`? Can't actually understand your query logic though ....

Answer (score 0):

> "There is a refnum in my query named as ULE.ULE_ORIGINAL_PFS"

Your query doesn't make sense, but maybe that's just the way you've edited it to post here.

> "I am confused to use either DECODE or NVL"

Perhaps use neither, but choose CASE() instead which is an industry standard:

```
AND ORF.ORDER_RELEASE_REFNUM_QUAL_GID =
                   case ULE.ULE_ORIGINAL_PFS
                        when 'MASTER_DATA_NO_AVAILABLE' then 0
                        when 'INVALID_ENTRY' then 0
                        else ULE.ULE_ORIGINAL_PFS
                   end
```